# Dell Inspiron 13Z - HDMI to TV not working

Tags: multiple-monitors, hdmi, tv, dell-inspiron

I just bought a **Dell 13z 5323** notebook running **Windows 8**, and connected an HDMI cable to a Panasonic TV, only to find that nothing is shown on the TV. I know for a fact that both the cable and the TV work (the HDMI output works with another notebook).

The graphic card is **Intel HD 4000**, and according to Dell's website, it is up to date.

When I plug in the HDMI cable, the notebook's screen flickers and then goes back to normal. The TV is shown as a recognized device, but nothing appears on the TV.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which OS is in question? If Windows, after you plug it in, does the TV show in the Display Properties?  Can/have you enabled it in there?

Comment: @techie007, please read updated post. Thanks

Comment: "The TV is shown as a recognized device" - Where are you seeing this?  Again, does it showing eh Display Properties, and can/have you enabled the display in said Display Properties?

Comment: @techie007, it appears under "Devices and Printers", and also when I go to "set up computer to use multiple monitors".

Comment: Does it show up in Control Panel\Appearance and Personalization\Display\Screen Resolution? Can/have you enabled the display in there?

Comment: Yes, it shows up there. But when I click on "Identify" the number "2" doesn't appear on the TV.

Comment: Is your TV set to the correct input source?

Comment: Yes. Anyway I tried them all. (3 hdmi ports on the tv)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, apparently it was an issue with the TV, because I tried with another and it worked. Anyway, Dell recommended downloading [this](http://t.co/oTetA5oM9D) BIOS driver update, which I haven't tried.

Answer (score 0):

** I had the same issue with the same DELL which I just bought a week ago. I successfully downloaded the link provided by DELL - and behold,it works like a charm. There was NO need to change screen resolution,etc.etc. I can watch now anything using my HDMI cable.Thanks a million for the download link. I would probably never knew if I wouldn't find this specific information. Thanks SO much!!**